# How to update UI from Firebase ML FaceDetectionProcessor

Tags: android, face-detection, ui-thread, firebase-mlkit, android-runonuithread

I have 2 Files:

1. Camera Activity
2. FaceDetectionProcessor(Firebase MLKit)

I have implemented `Firebase MLKit` for `Face detection` in my app. It consists of a file `FaceDetectionProcessor` having an `onSuccess` method which is called on each camera frame. I have passed a `TextView` to this file that needs to be updated from `onSuccess`.

Issue: The code gets executed but the value to the `TextView` does not update.

Observations:

1. The `TextView` value updates when called from the constructor of `FaceDetectionProcessor` but does not update when called from `onSuccess()`.
   Tried using `runInUIThread()` and `AsyncTaskThread(doInBackground)` but didn't work.
2. Since the call to `onSuccess` is continuous, `AsyncTaskThread` crashes the app with error that the task is already executed.

CameraActivity:

```
/*Call to the FaceDetectionProcessor' constructor*/
cameraSource.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(new 
    FaceDetectionProcessor (this, getResources(), requestCode, 
    cameraSource, myTextView));
```

FaceDetectionProcessor:

```
@Override
protected void onSuccess(
        @Nullable Bitmap originalCameraImage,
        @NonNull List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces,
        @NonNull FrameMetadata frameMetadata,
        @NonNull GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
    myTextView.setText("someValue");
}
```